# Add append html to QUnit output results for specific tests

Tags: javascript, qunit

I'm testing a set of algorithms. Each have the same purpose but have different results which can be viewed graphically in a chart.

I have unit tests for each algorithm. I would like to have a link in the appropriate QUnit test output results that opens the graph for the algorithm being tested.

The problem is I can't find a non-hack way of doing this. My best idea so far:

First, write the test:

```
module("Test algo 1");

test("test with inputs 1", ...);
test("test with inputs 2", ...);
```

Then write separate code that records what link should be added to the code:

```
addAlgoLink("Test algo 1", "test with inputs 1", function()
{
    // on click code for the link that displays the
    // input/output data on a graph
})
```

Then the implementation of `addAlgoLink()` would:

1. Add a callback to QUnit on completion of all tests.
2. On completion of tests, look through DOM of QUnit results for entries with a matching module name and test name, then append a link with the callback given to `addAlgoLink()`. It would be easier to use QUnit's hash ID for each test as it is used in the DOM, but I can't find a way of accessing a test's ID from within the test definition

Problems:

1. Cannot handle multiple tests in a module with the same name (although I don't know if QUnit supports this anyway)
2. It would need complex code to deal with differing depths of tests (nested modules)
3. It just seems really hacky.

Perhaps QUnit could be extended in a more elegant way? E.g. within the test code, a method could be called to specify the on click callback which gets inserted as a link such that the test and module name need not be specified again. Then extend the QUnit results outputter to display the link. Perhaps it could be stored within QUnit's `Test` objects, although I think most or all of the methods etc needed to do so are private which makes this seem impossible (not that it would have been a good idea).

Is what I'm trying to do just a really bad idea in the first place? Or is it just that the solution will have to be messy?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `QUnit.config.current.testId` within the test to record its id.

First write a test like this:

```
QUnit.test("Test 1", function( assert )
{
    addTestAppendage("Test 1", QUnit.config.current.testId);
    assert.ok(true);
});
```

Then use this code to look for the added test in the results and append a button to the test results row which runs a closure when clicked.

```
var appendages = [];
var addTestAppendage = function(testName, testId){
    appendages [testId] = testName;
};

QUnit.testDone(function(details){
    if (typeof appendages[details.testId] !== 'undefined')
    {
        var testRowSelector = "#qunit-test-output-" + details.testId;
        var testRow = $(testRowSelector);
        testRow.append("<button class=\"view\">View Graph</button>");
        var viewButtonSelector = testRowSelector + " button.view";
        $(viewButtonSelector).on('click', function(){
            // do stuff given the test name
            console.log(details.name);
        });
    }
});
```